# Extract text between ~ tags

Tags: c#, regex

I have have following string:

```
~header1
content1
content2
content3
content4
~header2
content5
content6
content7
content8
~header3
content9
content10
content11
content12
~header4
```

I need to extract the content between each header (`~header`) using regular expression in C# language. How to accomplish that?

I tried with the following code:

```
string pattern = "\\~.*\\~"; 

MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(data , pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline ) ;
```

But not getting any output.

So there will be an array as an output, suppose its name `m` with its content:

```
m[0] = "~header1|content1|content2|content3|content4"; 
m[1] = "~header2|content5|content6|content7|content8";
etc
```

Comment: You have to use `RegexOptions.Singleline`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick for you

```
string[] m = Regex.Split(value1, @"(?=~header)").Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lookarounds` here.

```
(?<=~header\d+)[\s\S]*?(?=~header\d+)

string strRegex = @"(?<=~header\d+)[\s\S]*?(?=~header\d+)";
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, RegexOptions.None);
string strTargetString = @"~header1" + "\n" + @"content1" + "\n" + @"content2" + "\n" + @"content3" + "\n" + @"content4" + "\n" + @"~header2" + "\n" + @"content5" + "\n" + @"content6" + "\n" + @"content7" + "\n" + @"content8" + "\n" + @"~header3" + "\n" + @"content9" + "\n" + @"content10" + "\n" + @"content11" + "\n" + @"content12" + "\n" + @"~header4";

foreach (Match myMatch in myRegex.Matches(strTargetString))
{
  if (myMatch.Success)
  {
    // Add your code here
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to match anything starting with `~` followed by any character other than `~`, and then replace newlines with a pipe:

```
var res = Regex.Matches(data, @"~[^~]*").Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(p => p.Value.Replace("\r\n", "|").TrimEnd('|'))
                  .ToList();
```

Result:

[image]

If you have mixed linebreaks, you will need another `Regex.Replace(p, @"\r?\n|\r", "|")` inside the `.Select`.